# pie chart position and tight_layout() in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to change pie chart position inside subplot in Matplotlib using `set_position`. Here is an example:

```
from pylab import *

fig = figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
hist(random(35))

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
hist(random(35))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(223)
hist(random(35))

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224,aspect=1)
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'long long label ......', 'd']
x = [118, 53, 48, 29, 20]
pie(x, labels=labels)
ax4.set_position([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
tight_layout(rect=[0,0,1,1])
show()
```

When I use `set_position` with `tight_layout` I get ugly result. How to change pie chart position correctly with `tight_layout`?

Comment: place `ax4.set_position` after `tight_layout` and change it to something like `ax4.set_position([0.4, 0, 0.5, 0.5])`